# MySql Query to select 6 employees whose salaries sum upto total of $50,000

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know mysql but i dont know how this type of query will be executed.
I need a query that can select 6 employees whose salaries sum upto a total of $50,000.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: show you data sample  .. and  your code ..

Comment: Please show your data structure.

Comment: what should the criteria be for selecting those 6 employees? there can be multiple combinations that sum up to 50000

Comment: I have a table that has the following fields.
1- emp_name
2- Salary
3- Projection_rate
so the criteria is to select 6 employees whose salary sum upto $50,000 and whose have the high projection rate, these two are the criterias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible by retrieving all the records from the database and on the same time adding their salaries, when the rows number was 6 sum was equal to 50,000, then skip all the rows. This way i got 6 records whose sum of salaries was equal or less then 50,000. Code given below:

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM mma_player ORDER BY my_proj DESC");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

```
                        $salary = $row['salary']; 
                        $a = $salary + $salary_count;

                    if($row_count > 4 && $a > 50000){
                        continue;
                        }
                    if($row_count > 6){
                        continue;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with 5 joins.  The following makes a few assumptions about the table structure:

```
select *
from employees e1 join
     employees e2
     on e1.employee_id < e2.employee_id join
     employees e3
     on e2.employee_id < e3.employee_id join
     employees e4
     on e3.employee_id < e4.employee_id join
     employees e5
     on e4.employee_id < e5.employee_id join
     employees e6 
     on e5.employee_id < e6.employee_id 
where (e1.salary + e2.salary + e3.salary + e4.salary + e5.salary + e6.salary) = 50000
```

Comment: @MuhammadHamid . . . How does it not work?  It exactly implements what you are asking for (after making reasonable assumptions about the data structure).

Comment: I was actually looking for the possible way to achieve some random rows from the database whose sum of salaries is equal or less then 50,000 , but actually this was not possible with just one query, i was using PHP for the retrieving of records so i figured out this was possible with some checks in PHP, the checks i made worked, and it is

Comment: if($row_count > 4 && $a > 50000){
                            continue;
                            }
                        if($row_count > 6){
                            continue;
                        }

Comment: I actually had to skip the rows after the sum of salaries was equal to 50,000.. in this way i was getting 6 rows whose salaries were equal to 50,000
And yeah thanks for your help mate :)